# Maven: package one module causes unnecessary "package" of dependencies

Tags: java, maven

I work with a large Maven project with many modules. When I run `mvn package -pl mymodule`, it first runs the `package` lifecycle phase of all the modules that `mymodule` depends on.

Some of these other modules have a maven-assembly-plugin step to create .tar.gz files, which is annoyingly slow.

I only need compilation of the other modules and creating their jars in order to create the assembly for `mymodule`. Yet because of the way this project is structured, packaging mymodule always requires all dependencies to be re-assembled.

What's the preferred way to speed up this build?

Comment: Can you deploy your dependencies to your local maven repo, or better, to a shared artifact repository like Nexus? And are all dependencies via SNAPSHOT, version ranges, or strictly versioned? The best solution can vary depending on your situation.

Comment: The dependencies are all in this single monolithic repo. Aha - I just tried installing to my local repo by mvn install, and now it does not attempt to build dependencies when I run mvn package. Post that as answer and I'll accept; thanks!

Comment: Actually, it looks like the key was to avoid the -am flag after installing. Before running 'mvn install', omitting -am caused failure, but now I can safely leave it out. So this alleviates the problem but doesn't really solve it fully, because on the first "mvn install" I am still unnecessarily creating assemblies.

Comment: check this SO post, it will give you further hints http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35603795/what-is-the-difference-between-using-maven-pl-option-and-running-maven-from-mod