# Maven build error only when triggered from sub module

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, java-11

*Maven version 3.8.2* - Java version 11.0.12 -

I have a very strange problem. I have this multimodule project:

```
-Root-module
  -moduleA
  -moduleB
  -moduleC
```

When I run this from the **root module** everything is fine:

```
mvn clean install -am -pl :moduleA -Pjava11
```

But when i run this very similar command from the **directory of moduleA** (which still should be exactly the same thing imo)

```
mvn -f ../pom.xml clean install -am -pl :moduleA -Pjava11
```

I have a build error that I don't get on the first version.

> ```
>  [XJC Error] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:2.5.0:xjc (xjc) on project some-module-X:  [ERROR] +=================== [XJC Error]
> ```

My question is aren't these two approaches identical?

```
-f ../pom.xml === cd ../
```

And either case how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Why not running from root module (which is correct) ? What is the real problem? Apart from that I can't understand what is causing the issue because I don't know your whole project.... The other question is: Why do you even need `install`?

Comment: @khmarbaise thx. You mean I should use verify and not install? Can you elobrate?

Comment: My guess is that that plugin is not correctly handling the relative path.